# WPF Slide Transition when Image change source (Is this even possible?)

Tags: c#, ios, wpf, vb.net, itunesartwork

In iOS7 Music app, when the track changes, the album cover will change with a slide transition

[image: In iOS7 Music app, when the track changes, the album cover will change with a slide transition]

in WPF, I'm using iTunes COM and I replace the image source in the onplayerplayevent, is it possible to add a slide transition when the image change source?

if possible, can i add two transitions? slide left when i press the previous button and slide right when the song finishes and when i press the next button.

Thanks anyway. Just tell me if this is possible.

Comment: It is possible with two adjacent Image controls in a common container that clips them.

Answer (score 1):

Developing view transitions from scratch is no easy feat, but luckily enough, there are pre-written libraries that can do this for us. I found a really useful library that you can use for this purpose. It features many different transitions (not just sliding transitions), just like PowerPoint and is really easy to use. It is called `Transitionals` and you can download it from the CodePlex website:

[Transitionals](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/)

This `Transitionals` library is now on version 1.2, but you can download the help file for version 1.0 by clicking on the 'TransitionalsHelp_1_0.zip' link on [this page](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/releases/view/12954) on CodePlex.

Comment: i tried this one. theres no slide transition just like in iOS is what i need :(